# Google Sheets - Finding the average of lowest 8 values from 20 most recent (rolling)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula, rolling-average

new to all this.
Doing a golf spreadsheet and need to find out the average of lowest 8 rounds from the last 20 rounds.
As I add in another scorecard, the calculation will move along etc.

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

Any ideas on how I can get started?
Thanks in advance

Comment: please share an actual example sheet rather than just an image...

Comment: What are the last 20 rounds in your picture and what means lowest 8 rounds, the lowest sum, the lowest average, the lowest 8 single values? Can you make a clearer example.

Answer (score 2):

As you also tagged `excel-formula`, based on [this formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/sum-bottom-n-values) for bottom n values, guessing that you want the average of the lowest column sums of most recent number of columns, a solution to your this guess would be

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(OFFSET(A4:E4,,COUNTA(A4:J4)-5),{1,2,3}))
```

[image]

This formula gets the average of the lowest 3 column-sums(yellow row) of 5 most recent rounds (5 rightmost rows). You need to adapt the ranges.

For your case i can only guess, where your data starts.

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(OFFSET(A23:T23,,COUNTA(A23:ZZ23)-20),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}))
```

`A23:T23` has to start at the first round (column). `COUNTA(A23:ZZ23)-20` hast to start at first round (column) and has to be at least as long as the number of expected rounds. It counts the number of not-empty cells to get the last round and subtracts 20 to get the start of the last 20 rounds(columns)

I suppose, there should be a similar functionality in google-sheets, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: For Google sheets, "all" you have to do is put the SMALL function inside an ARRAYFORMULA function. The second example will become:
```=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(SMALL(OFFSET(A23:T23,,COUNTA(A23:ZZ23)-20),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})))```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in a vertical table. In column D is the Score differential for each round (columns A-C are the date, golf course and the holes). The function then becomes:

```
=AVERAGE(arrayformula(SMALL(OFFSET(D1:D$27,,,20),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})))
```

Row 27 is the first entry, every new entry goes above line 1. I then copy the formula to the new cell E1 (D$27 will change to D$28 if you add a line above line 1)

`OFFSET(D1:D$27,,,20)` returns the first 20 rows of the range `D1:D$27`
`ARRAYFORMULA(SMALL(..., {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}))` Creates an array of 8 elements. The elements are `SMALL(...,1)`, `SMALL(...,2)` ... `SMALL(...,8)`. And the `AVERAGE` function takes the avareage of those 8 values. (`SMALL(...,n)` returns the nth smallest values of the provided range)

In a separate spreadsheet, I calculate the score differential based on the CR, SR, PAR, SI and handicap table.